# How do you flip an equation (exchange LHS with RHS) in Maple?

Tags: swap, equation, maple

I have an equation which has been reduced to the form

```
eqn1 := f(x,y,z) = T;
```

Now I have another equation that involves T as a variable

```
eqn2 := g(T,x,y,z);
```

I want to replace `T` with `f(x)` in `eqn2`. If I had `eqn1` in the form

```
eqn1better := T = f(x,y,z);
```

Then the following command would do what I want.

```
algsubs(eqn1better, eqn2);
```

So how do I swap the left-hand side and the right-hand side of an equation to turn `eqn1` into `eqn1better`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maple gives you the functions `lhs` and `rhs`, have you tried using them.

```
eqn1 := f(x,y,z) = T;
eqn1better := rhs(eqn1) = lhs(eqn1)
```

Comment: Nope, I was unaware of these functions. Your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon another function to do what I want. It only works in the specific case of

```
eqn1 := f(x) = T
```

but using the `isolate` function will also solve the problem I have specified.

```
eqn1better := isolate(eqn1, T);
```

adamse's answer is better because it solves the general case of reversing any equation, regardless of whether or not one side is a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the bigger problem, you should consider `eliminate`.  You can just to `eliminate({eqn1,eqn2},T)` and get as a result both the substitution and the result.